# Extreme Value Theorem for complex valued functions statement verification

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

In lectures we defined $\overline E := E \cup (\partial E)$, where $E$ is an open sbset of $\mathbb C$. We then stated the following analogue of the Extreme Value Theorem for complex valued functions:

> Let $\overline E$ be a closed bounded subset of $\mathbb C$ and suppose that $f: \overline E \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is continuous. Then $f$ is bounded, i.e. $\exists M > 0$ such that $|f(z)| \leq M$, for all $z \in E$.

Should this instead be $z \in \overline E$? Or are we only able to bound the function on the interior of the domain (but in this case it doesn't seem to hard to extend our $M$ to some $M'$ that extends the bound of the function to the boundary too)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true for all $z\in\overline{E}$ i.e. the function is bounded also on $\overline{E}$.